# MongoDB Compass aggregations $match filter returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I have collection in mongodb and its size is 5.7 million.
But I have problem with the $match filter.
I'm trying a **query** with this command:

```
{ date:{ $gte: "2019-07-16", $lte: "2019-07-16" } }
```

returns 10k documents.

But I'm trying **$match aggregations** with the same command and it returns nothing.

My sample document;

```
{
"_id":"5c1a231f1923047866f3ffb0",
"no":"20",
"id":"007",
"Typee":"Real",
"type":"noInternet",
"dealersTitle":"John",
"yesterday_total":"65.52",
"mastercard_number":"0",
"mastercard_total":"0",
"mastercard_balance":"0",
"rfCard_number":"6",
"rfCart_total":"65",
"rfBalance_number":"0",
"rfBalance_total":"0",
"todayBalance":"0.52",
"balanceRfTotal":"0",
"date":"2019-07-16"
}
```

I don't understand where the problem comes from.

**Edited:**
It returns result when I try aggregation on terminal. Why Mongo Compass doesn't see my collection in the aggregation tab. (N/A Documents in the Collection)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your actual queries and a sample document that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I added details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sample document shows that your date attribute is saved as string and not date.

{
"_id":"5c1a231f1923047866f3ffb0",
"no":"20",
"id":"007",
"Typee":"Real",
"type":"noInternet",
"dealersTitle":"John",
"yesterday_total":"65.52",
"mastercard_number":"0",
"mastercard_total":"0",
"mastercard_balance":"0",
"rfCard_number":"6",
"rfCart_total":"65",
"rfBalance_number":"0",
"rfBalance_total":"0",
"todayBalance":"0.52",
"balanceRfTotal":"0",
**"date":"2019-07-16"**
}

if you use data type as date you can easily compare dates.

**"date": {"$date":"2019-07-16"}**